# "Similar questions" widget doesn't repaint properly after scrolling until a dialog is opened

Tags: bug, design

On Firefox 81.0 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 18.04, if you ask a question on Stack Overflow or on Meta here, the "Similar questions" widget has a repaint bug when you scroll it:

[image: Shows a double-image]

The widget contents get painted twice, and only one of the painted images gets updated.

After opening another widget, such as the "Insert Image" dialog from pasting in a screenshot, the repaint bug goes away until you do something to cause the "Similar questions" widget to reload, which brings it back.

This might be a Firefox bug, but I do not know if that is the case.